# turn ringer on/off/vibrate based on location _ANDROID ECLIPSE

Tags: android, eclipse

i have working code for an app that receives latitude and longitude --- im working towards a goal that based on this longitude and latitude i set it will turn off the ringer --- its sounds pretty straight forward it just seems like i have programmers block and cant seem to move past this point----so my question is ---in what ways could i utilize the location services in android using eclipse to set a certain longitude and latitude coordinates to a place where when i enter that specific place it turns off the ringer for me or any variation of the ringer on/off/vibrate/silent

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question. You stand a chance of getting voted down because of that.... But, to start you should read up on Location Services and Location Manager. the concept is that you start by getting your "Last Known Location" from location service and begin to dial in your precise location using Network_Service and GPS_Service. From scratch it could take a minute or so to actually get a GPS location and it consumes battery so you have to start and stop "Locating" judiciously to maintain a good location and preserve battery. As for turning the ringer off??  You should also tag this as Android and put some code together or at least an idea and repost.

Make sense? start reading here [Android Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html)